# Aliased types in Go only assignable if unnamed?

Tags: types, go, assign

In the following code snippet the last three assignments produce a compilation error:

```
package main

type (
    Foo []float64
    Baz [2]float64
    Meh map[string]string
    Faq chan int
    Tet func()
    Hue interface{}
    Tai bool
    Foz string
    Bar float64
)

func main() {
    var ( 
        foo Foo = []float64{1, 2, 3}
        _ []float64 = foo

        baz Baz = [...]float64{1, 2}
        _ [2]float64 = baz

        meh Meh = make(map[string]string)
        _ map[string]string = meh

        faq Faq = make(chan int)
        _ chan int = faq

        tet Tet = func() { return }
        _ func() = tet

        hue Hue = "Hello, World"
        _ interface{} = hue

        tai Tai = true
        _ bool = tai // error

        foz Foz = "Hello, World"
        _ string = foz // error

        bar Bar = 1
        _ float64 = bar // error
    )
}
```

This means that, in this example, only bools, strings and floats are not assignable.
The reason for this can be found in the specification:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
>   T") in any of these cases:
>
> - [...]
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - [...]

([Go Specification: Assignability](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability))

and

> [...] Named types are specified by a (possibly qualified) type name; unnamed types are specified using a type literal, which composes a new type from existing types. [...]

([Go Specification: Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types))

Combining this, the reason why the aliased assign does not work is because the types of the last three cases are named. Through this the rule is violated: Two named types are part of the assignment.

Now to my actual question(s):

Why should it not be allowed to assign an aliased string/bool/numeric to an actual string/bool/numeric, as opposed to types like slices and arrays?

What kinds of problems would the lack of this rule cause?

What kinds of problems would the specification of a string as a named type cause?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're certainly allowed to ask "why couldn't I have a different language?" questions on Stack Overflow, and the answer is probably "seems like you could, now you just have to actually build it." I'm more into answering questions that help folks build things than academic ones, though.

Comment: @twotwotwo Well, the main reason I ask this question is because I know that the designers of Go put a lot of thought into it, so there is presumably some sort of idea behind such a decision that I do not see. I am sorry that this question is not to solve a specific problem, but more of a question on language design (in general, because I presume Go is not the only language that enforces this rule). I was asking here hoping that somebody who knows more about language design than me could ellaborate why things are generally done this way.

Comment: I think there's a way of addressing this as a programming question ("how do I use the non-assignability of two named types?), and I'm giving that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignability rules mean you sometimes have to convert between named types to explicitly say "yes, I mean this `string` to be used as a `Foo`," even if they share the same underlying type. This is relevant to things like `os.FileMode`: it's a number underneath, but type checks will keep you from accidentally passing it to a function that takes an unrelated `foo uint32`. (Assignability rules affect function calls, too: you can pass an argument of any type that's assignable to the parameter type.)

Generally, this means if you have distinct, potentially confusable uses for an underlying type, you can assign different names to them. Like: the underlying type `[][4]float32` could plausibly have `RGBASlice`, `HSVASlice`, and `XYZWSlice` type names assigned. You can't pass a `RGBASlice` to a function that expects an `XYZWSlice`. But all can be passed transparently to things that don't care about the meanings of the numbers, like if you have some all-purpose vector-math routines.

So, broadly, by forcing you to convert between named types, Go helps you distinguish between things that might have the same representation in memory even though they have different meanings and are supposed to be used different places.

Comment: If you're really into what you can do with fancy type tricks, check out languages like ML or Rust. Go tries to keep things pretty basic in comparison.

Comment: First off, thank you. Secondly, does that essentially mean that the types declared by Go as named types are in practice more likely to be confused for something else when aliased? Your answer makes the strictness of assignability seem like an advantage for named types ("[...] but type checks will keep you from accidentally passing it to a function that takes an unrelated foo uint32"), but at the same time, the inverted argument like an advantage for unnamed types ("But all can be passed transparently to things that don't care about the meanings of the numbers [...]").

Comment: Hmm. I think *a* way to think of it here is that you name a type to declare there's some special meaning beyond the components. `[][4]float32` is *any* slice of float32 arrays, no additional meaning, so it will happily take an `RGBASlice`. `RGBASlice` and `XYZWSlice` *do* have distinct meanings and if you want to pass one as the other you need a conversion to tell the compiler it's on purpose.

Comment: I'm not saying that's how the authors think of it, or that it'd be crazy to make a language where unnamed<->named assignments require explicit conversion. It's just one way I might think about when to use a `[][4]float32` vs. an `RGBASlice` if I were writing code that dealt with both.

Comment: It remains that the compiler treats `uint32` and `FileMode` as non-assignable but not `[][4]float32` and `RGBASlice`--that does work out in practice but no grand theory as to why that outcome is inherently right.